# raspberry shell cant run after some minutes

Tags: linux, shell

```
#!/bin/bash 
while true;do 
    echo "1" >> /home/pi/c/1.txt 
    sleep 5s 
done
```

I set the script auto run at boot.

1. put it into /etc/init.d/
2. update-rc.d scrpit.sh defaults

The question is :
the script can can for some minutes ,but it will stop write 1.txt file after some minutes,
what the problem.

Comment: Is the process still running (`ps -ef`)? What's the last update time of the file (`ls -al /home/pi/c/1.txt`)? Is true somehow returning false? Only two of those are serious questions :-)

Comment: the process still running the 1.txt file is writen for some minutes probalby 30minutes

Comment: Do you really have everything on one line like that? You can't have commands on the same line as `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: I've seen unusual things happen due to a bad SDcard. Maybe you can replace the SDcard.